# How do i download a github repository using git clone

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have a github link: https://github.com/TarrySingh/Artificial-Intelligence-Deep-Learning-Machine-Learning-Tutorials/tree/master/machine-learning

i want to use the git clone to download the file in this repository in my local environment (named dog-project) in my anarconda.

i tried the code below:

```
(dog-project) C:\Users\chenl>git clone https://github.com/TarrySingh/Artificial-Intelligence-Deep-Learning-Machine-Learning-Tutorials/tree/master/machine-learning

Cloning into 'machine-learning'...
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/TarrySingh/Artificial-Intelligence-Deep-Learning-Machine-Learning-Tutorials/tree/master/machine-learning/' not found
```

it failed, how can i fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to clone the tree instead of the repo. Run `git clone` with the same address, minus the "/tree/master/machine-learning".

Comment: it works! thx, but what if i just want that specific folder? is there any way to do that?

Comment: There is, but it's complicated through the command line. The easiest way would be using [DownGit](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home) to download the folder from the tree you want. You can paste your original link in there and it will output a .zip for you.

Comment: thank you so much. it makes my life easier!

Comment: [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/7976758)